# ImportError: No module named in IDA script

Tags: python, ida

I executed a IDA test.py script on Ubuntu with this command './idal -S"test.py" -t', 
there would be a error - no module named xxx, i imported xxx module in this script,  but when i separately executed test.py, it is OK. 
I do not know why this happened? 
why it can not find xxx module? 
but when i execute it under Windows version IDA, it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your `test.py` in another directory. The file `python.cfg` in the `cfg` folder in the ida directory contains the following by default:

> // Remove current directory from import search path

```
   REMOVE_CWD_SYS_PATH = 1
```

Please let me know if this helped.